# Find index of array starting at specific location

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

I want to use the following to find the index of '2'

```
let index = array.findIndex(c => c === '2');
```

The index would be 1 in this case, but I  want to purposely start at index 2 so the result would be 4 instead of 1.

Any thoughts?

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'];
let index = array.findIndex(c => c === '2');

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and set the `fromIndex` (2nd param) to 2:

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'];
const index = array.indexOf('2', 2);

console.log(index);
```

If you must use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (to find an object for example), you can use the 2nd param passed to the callback (the index) to limit the search:

```js
const array = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'];
const index = array.findIndex((c, idx) => idx > 1 && c === '2');

console.log(index);
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much. testing with my fn now